# Fractals and Kleinian groups - Rendering the limit set

Tags: limits, fractals, mobius-transformation, mobius-inversion

I am talking about this:

[image]

I recently read the book "The fractal geometry of nature" by Benoit B. Mandelbrot. There was one particular fractal I found very beautiful: A limit set of some group of ... well, it is "Homographien" in German, I don't exactly know the correct terminology in English. (I have the German translation​, there it is picture 190)

Now the problem: I don't understand it, but I really want to!
I did quite some research, but I found nothing that was helpful to me. (Neither I found stuff that I understand)

I know it is somehow related to IFS (right?), but again: I have no clue. But I know that the formula $f(z) = \frac{az + b}{cz + d}$ with $ad - bc = 1$, which is called a möbius-transformation, I think. But I don't know if $z$ is complex and the same goes for the parameters.

My goal is to a) understand what is going on in that picture and b) use that knowledge to write a programm that can draw it.

If I messed up the equations (or anything else), please correct me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The book [Indra's Pearls](http://klein.math.okstate.edu/IndrasPearls/) covers this stuff.  Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indra%27s_Pearls_%28book%29):

> Indra's Pearls: The Vision of Felix Klein is a geometry book written by David Mumford, Caroline Series and David Wright, and published by Cambridge University Press in 2002.
>
> The book explores the patterns created by iterating conformal maps of the complex plane called Möbius transformations, and their connections with symmetry and self-similarity. These patterns were glimpsed by German mathematician Felix Klein, but modern computer graphics allows them to be fully visualised and explored in detail.

Also, [Jos Leys](http://www.josleys.com/) has recently developed [an escape time algorithm for Kleinian group limit sets](http://www.josleys.com/articles/Kleinian%20escape-time_3.pdf), which is faster and more effective for certain cases.  Figure 16 in the article is quite similar to your image.

Comment: Hm, I'll take a look at this book. It seems a very interesting topic. Thank you for the article!